# Load HTML from URL into DIV (Java, GWT/GXT)

Tags: java, html, gwt, gxt

How can I load html page and insert its content into div element? I don't want to use ContentPanel.setUrl (for example), because it will create IFrame
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use Gxt's `HtmlContainer` class and it's `setUrl()` method:

[http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.1/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/HtmlContainer.html#setUrl(java.lang.String)](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.1/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/HtmlContainer.html#setUrl%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use RequestBuilder go get content of given url:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/DevGuideHttpRequests

Remember about [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) - if you want to get content of a page from other domain then you will need to write GWT service which will make the server download the content and return to your application through RPC.

Comment: hmmm... I'm getting content (from same domain), but javascripts in this content don't work :(